# regular expression for finding a word position followed or preceded by special character

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I want to find the position of a word in a long string. that word can be preceded or followed by a special character but not a alphanumeric character. so if I search for germany and string contains germany!! or $germany or $germany)( or germany i want its position. How can I write a regular expression for this. I tried this (?i)(?<=^|[^a-z])germany(?=$|[^a-z]) but it doesn't work.

```
String s="(?i)(?<=^|[^a-z])germany(?=$|[^a-z])";
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("(?i)(?<=^|[^a-z])cat(?=$|[^a-z])");
Matcher m=p.matcher(" germany@ is germany");
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

return a false everytime. Can you suggest a correct way. I want to find such words and replace them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although above answers is correct, it can be made more efficient using this regular expression

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<![^\\W_])" + string + "(?![^\\W_])");
```

Your job should take less time with this

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use `matcherobject.find()` method in-order to find a matched substring. matches method will try to check the regex against the whole input string.
2. `Pattern p= Pattern.compile("(?i)(?<=^|[^A-Z0-9a-z])germany(?=$|[^A-Z0-9a-z])");`

For not of alphanumeric , you need to use `A-Z0-9` also inside the negated character class.

```
ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList();
String s = "germany@ is germany";
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("(?i)(?<=^|[^a-zA-Z\\d])(g)ermany(?=$|[^a-zA-Z\\d])");
Matcher m=p.matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
positions.add(m.start());
}
System.out.println(positions);
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 12]
```

Comment: it works thanks. Although I was testing on the lowercase and non numeric data so how adding A-Z0-9 solved it. Also why do we add (g)ermany instead of germany?

Comment: How to make it case sensitive? it is currently matching GERMANY also, which I want to handle separatly EDIT : Removing (?i) from start will do it.

Comment: yep, `(?i)` called case-insensitive modifier.

Comment: is there by any chance it can cause infinite loop? I am not able to recreate any such issue but running my map reduce job is failing because out of memory error. I thought may be by any chance this matcher will go in infinite loop?